# Skype 4.0 keeps crashing

Tags: skype

I just installed Skype 4.0 for Linux and for some reason it crashed almost everytime I click on certain actions like **Mark all as viewed**, **Accept an invitation** etc...

Apparently It seems to work well for other and I couldn't find any help on that type of behaviour online. I do get the same behaviour on my box at work which makes me believe it comes from something I use but what ?

thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Ordinarily, I'd recommend that you report this as a bug. But, we all know MicroSoft's track record for fixing bugs...... My honest recommendation, until they release a further update, is to revert back to the version of Skype in the repositories.

Comment: What kernel version do you use?

Comment: 3.2.0-24-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright I figured it out.

It's somewhere on Skype bug report but I can't find the link anymore.

You need so set a country in your account profile.

Fix is :

Install skype 2.2 back
Open your profile & set a country
Voila

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed previous Skype in your Ubuntu ?
If so please remove it first before you install 4.0 version. 
I forgot the script but it's easy to find those script in Google or tutorials.

Comment: APT replaces the package for you...